# Permission ViewAllData depends on permission(s): ViewAllForecasts

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Getting this error while updating the Permission Set with "View All Data" permission through SFDX/ScratchOrg.
[image]

NOTE: We do not have forecast enabled.

Comment: Dear All, This issue is resolved. Actually we did not realised that Forecast was enabled in Staging and Production and because of that we were getting this error. In scratch org Forecast was not enabled.

Comment: It is resolved, actually there was Forecast enabled in Production but not in scratch org because of which we were getting this error.